# How to choose an optimal threshold for binary discretization

Tags: machine-learning, data, feature-engineering, features

We know that we usually do discretizations to continuous features to remove extra information and unwanted regularities, which makes the model robust and well-predicted.
But I am wondering except based on the **context** of feature how to choose an optimal threshold for data discretization, binary or multi.

Comment: I don't really understand at all the setup of this question. You state that we usually do discretizations to continous features to supposedly remove extra info, and makes the model "robust" but in reality this is poor practice in general and the opposite is true. Please see this thread on crossvalidated: stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68834/what-is-the-benefit-of-breaking-up-a-continuous-predictor-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting the **histogram** chart of that feature by different numbers of bins can be helpful. the **maximum width** of the bins in which the distribution of the data does not change noticeably can be a suitable choice.